# Sending data from client to server works but Server to client does not

Tags: c#, sockets, chat, tcpclient

I know that doing `Flush` operation on a network stream does nothing,

That's why I defined `StreamWriter` which takes the network stream as a constructor parameter, then I'm trying to send the client the letter `S` to tell him that his connection was successful.

```
private StreamReader srReceiver;
private StreamWriter swSender;

// Occures when a new client is accepted
private void AcceptClient()
{
    srReceiver = new System.IO.StreamReader(TcpClient.GetStream());
    swSender = new System.IO.StreamWriter(TcpClient.GetStream());

    if (TcpClient.Available > 0)
    {
            char [] buff0 = new char[TcpClient.Available];

            // Read the account information from the client
            srReceiver.Read(buff0, 0, TcpClient.Available);

            sUserNumber = new string(buff0);

            // We got a response from the client
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sUserNumber))
            {
                OraEntities Ent = new OraEntities();

                var user = Ent.USERS.FirstOrDefault(usr => usr.USER_NUMBER == sUserNumber);

                // Check user validity
                if (user == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No user has this number: " + sUserNumber);
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Add the user to Active Users List and start listening for messages from him
                    Server.AddUser(this, sUserNumber);

                    // S means connected successfully
                    swSender.WriteLine("S");
                    swSender.Flush();

                    // Start the new tread that hosts the listener
                    thrReceive = new Thread(HandleInput);
                    thrReceive.Start();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                CloseConnection();
                return;
            }
    }
}
```

But nothing is being sent on the wire (There is no run-time exceptions).

What am I missing?

Comment: Try adding a CRLF (\r\n) after each line: swSender.WriteLine("S\r\n");

Comment: It might be worth using a `using(Stream s = TcpClient.GetStream()) that surrounds your code inside the AcceptClient and then writing directly to the stream rather than using a stream writer.

Comment: @DarrenDavies tried it, not working.

Comment: @Gavin tried it, now I get exception `The operation is not allowed on non-connected sockets` because when I used `using`, disposal of the network stream happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my test code, showing it working:

Server:

```
namespace SocketTestServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener lis = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 2509);
            lis.Start();
            lis.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(acceptClient), lis);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void acceptClient(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            TcpListener lis = ar.AsyncState as TcpListener;
            using (TcpClient cli = lis.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar))
            {
                using (NetworkStream ns = cli.GetStream())
                {
                    byte[] toSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("S\r\n");
                    ns.Write(toSend, 0, toSend.Length);
                    Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
namespace SocketTestClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
            {
                client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 2509);
                using (NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream())
                {
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);
                    Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Which the screenshot below, show working:

[image: Screenshot of client/server working]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this yesterday. Below is the question
[Read data from socket, send response and close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806577/read-data-from-socket-send-response-and-close).

Its the last answer, haven't been able to accept it though as I need to wait 2 days.

Hopefully this will help

Comment: My issue is that 'If I closed the network stream (so the data can be sent), how can I connect the TcpClient again?'. Since, when I'm trying to use the NetworkStream again, I receive InvalidOperationException that I can't access disposed object.